# Heat sink design

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, heatsink

I'd like to implement some kind of heat sink to cool down the following step-down power converter: https://www.pololu.com/product/2851, but I have zero experience with heat sink techniques. The converter board has components on both sides of the PCB, so it's not obvious to me if I can use some kind of sil-pad.

What are my options? Adding a fan is not one of them, and the whole package needs to remain reasonably small.

Comment: You haven't listed any information about how much heat you need to dissipate, and what the temperature range of the air that your going to dump this heat into.

Comment: In addition, looks like the design of the board does not assume application of the heat sink - at any of its sides at to any of its components.

Comment: From the product page: "During normal operation, this product can get hot enough to burn you. Take care when handling this product or other components connected to it." It's expected to get quite hot then, do you need a heatsink for some other reason?

Comment: @laptop2d I don't know how much heat I need to dissipate. Input will be a 2s Li-ion pack (~7.4 V), and output will be 5V, ~3 A.

Comment: @Samuel "Hot enough to burn you" is poorly constrained. I'm more concerned about "hot enough to melt plastic and/or generate plastic fumes"

Comment: @Mathieu go on digikey and find a 15W heatsink and fasten it to the components that are getting warm. Another thing I've used in the past is a piece of aluminum and tape or thermal epoxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a switching regulator. At output power of 5V*3A = 15 W the board will dissipate about 1 - 1.5 W (looking at datasheet ~92 - 95% efficiency of converter with 6V-12V input). This is not much, and it should work without any extra heat sink.

However, if the module operates in completely non-ventilated enclosure, with no air flow at all, you might want to provide extra thermal path for the generated heat. From the datasheet drawings/pictures, the most likely components to generate heat are at the bottom of PCB. The components, luckily, are all in about even height, so it should be possible to use one of thermal managing materials (either a thermal epoxy, or a sort of conductive soft plastic) and attach the back of PCB to some metal-made thermal conductor, aka "heat sink". Look, for example, at [**Aavid-Thermalloy**](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/supplier/library/pdf/Aavidselectionguide.pdf) product line, for Ther-O-Bond adhesives or In-Sil-8 Pads, and then select proper size heat sink (for 1-2W of dissipation capability), or attach the module to a metal wall of your enclosure (if any). I think this is your most reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

A heatsink is a thermal circuit, temperature is like a voltage, heat will flow from hot to cold and will be impeded by thermal resistance.

The first thing to do is determine how much power needs to be moved (like current) and then what the thermal resistance is of the system (usually listed in W/mK (or Watts per meter kelvin) for the thickness of the material. 
This means that the thickness of your material will determine how much thermal resistance, it also means you can calculate the temperature drop across a thermal resistor (or material) if you have the measurment of its thermal conductive

For example, if I have 20W that is moving through a 1cm thick thermal pad with a 5W/mK thermal conductivity I will get a drop of:

First calculate thermal conductivity of pad (0.01m) \$ \frac{5W}{mK} = \frac{0.05 W}{K}\$

Then calculate the temperature drop (similar to a real resistor) 
\$ \frac{20W} {5W/K} = 20W *\frac{1}{5}\frac{K}{W}= 4K =4C \$
so there would be a 4 degree drop across the thermal pad.

Suppose the temperature of the heated side of the pad is 80C, with a 4 degree drop, the other side of the pad will be 76C.

You will then need to do this for each thermal resistor in the system.

If you notice that the conductivity is related to the distance, this is one reason thermal paste is much more effective at moving heat, because you can get it extremely thin.

In general the material with the lowest thermal conductivity (opposite of resistance, or material with highest thermal resistance) will be the limiter for your thermal system.

Heatsinks can be rated for power, and need to be sized appropriately for the power that needs to be dissipated. There is a whole science to it, but without getting into thermal advection, you can size a heatsink with the following:

Source: [SMPS](http://www.smps.us/thermal.html)

> When designing a heat sink for a semiconductor cooling, first of all
>   you need to choose the component's maximum operating junction
>   temperature Tjmax (typically, we select 105-120 oC for commercial
>   parts). Then, for convection cooling the required heatsink thermal
>   resistance should be Rth-hs<(Tjmax-Ta)/P-(Rthj-c+Rthc-hs) oC/W, where
>   Ta- ambient, Rthj-c - thermal resistance between junction and the case
>   from the datasheet (typically 0.5-2.5 oC/W for conventional discrete
>   power packages), Rthc-hs - thermal resistance between the device's
>   case and the heatsink, P- power dissipated by the device in watts.
>   Besides conduction cooling, there is another path for the heat- from
>   the case of the device directly to the air. This path is defined by
>   junction to ambient thermal resistance Rthj-amb. However, you can
>   usually disregard it when a device is mount onto a heatsink.
>
> heatsink design thermal circuit See thermal circuit diagram to the
>   left for an illustration. Once you found the required Rth-hs, you can
>   pick a stamped or extruded heat sink with equal or lower value of
>   thermal resistance. Note that if you use an insulator between the
>   device and the heatsink, you need to take it into account as well. For
>   off-the-shelf parts, Rth-hs is normally specified in the datasheet.
>   Harry Lythall found empirically a "rule of thumb" calculation formula
>   for Rth-hs of home made U-shape folded aluminum sheet. Based on his
>   equation, the required surface area in sq.cm is A=(50/Rth-hs)2. In
>   general, the main optimization criteria are to maximize the exposed
>   heat exchanger's surface area, and to minimize its weight and the mean
>   distance of the exposed surface from the component to be cooled.

[image]

Because the heatsink cannot use a fan, you will need much more area to dissipate the heat, thermal grease will give you better performance.

In some cases simply a piece of sheet metal can do wonders for dissipating heat.

Since there are a lot of variables with thermal systems, it is good to buy a few options and test all the options before finishing your project.